# Which settings in Aim Lab map to Destiny 2?

Tags: destiny-2, aim-lab

[Aim Lab](https://store.steampowered.com/app/714010/Aim_Lab/) has a number of settings in the game to help mimic the setup of common FPS games, such as Overwatch.

However it doesn't have a pre-configured setup for Destiny 2.

What settings should I set to best mimic Destiny 2 when training with Aim Lab?